# Name of an electronic component

Tags: identification, wireless, radio

Can anybody kindly tell me what this electronic component in the picture is called?

I've seen this component in:

- Mobile phone circuit
- WiMax modem circuit
- GSM Module circuit

[image: The component on a mobile phone circuit]

[image: Closer top view of the component]

I tried but was unable to find its name. I'll be grateful to know your answers.

Comment: Some kind of small-form-factor coaxial connector, isn't it?

Comment: SMA connector.. You connect an antenna to it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, definitely not SMA, which is much larger and has threads. More likely MCX or MMCX, but I can't tell the exact scale from the pictures provided. Could be even smaller than those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a "SWG" type connector with embedded switch,

[image]

[Murata part number](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/switch/switch/o33e.ashx?la=en-us) MM8030-2610RK0 or similar.

The idea of this connector is to provide a smooth connection to external antenna or for testing/diagnostics/calibration purpose of RF channel.

In normal (unconnected) state the center pin is loaded with a termination resistor to avoid back reflections on RF signal, or to internal network connected to on-board antenna (PCB or special ceramic).

When a special matching plug is connected, the center pin switches (mechanically) from the PCB network to the connected cable, maintaining good impedance matching.

Comment: So this thing doesn't have anything to do with RF signal transmission/reception? I mean, will the RF circuit still work after I detach the "connector"?

Comment: @user170786, what do you mean "nothing to do with RF"? It is a RF switch. It could switch between internal on-board antenna and external cable/antenna. So yes, the circuit could still "work" in either position.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, see correct answer below.

<s>Looks like a U.FL connector, likely for RF testing during manufacturing. It does seem to be the opposite gender from what is typically found on a board.
See: [Hirose U.FL](https://www.hirose.com/product/en/products/U.FL/)</s>

Comment: This is pretty wrong. U.FL connectors have a pin in the center, not a hole.